# python override environment variable in local scope

Tags: python, perl, environment-variables

How can I override the environment variable in a local scope? I know how to do it in perl, but not python.

In perl:

```
if (1)
{
    local $ENV{PATH} = "/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin";
    print "$ENV{PATH}\n";
}
print "$ENV{PATH}\n";
```

the output would be:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

Any idea how to do the same in python?

Well, one way to do that is to save the environment variable before the scope starts and retrieve it when it ends. But I wonder if there is a nicer way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using python's `with` statement:

```
from sys import argv
import os

class MyPath(object):
    def __init__(self, newpath):
        self.newpath = newpath

    def __enter__(self):
        self.path = os.environ['PATH']
        os.environ['PATH'] = self.newpath
        return self.newpath

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        os.environ['PATH'] = self.path

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(argv) < 2:
        print "usage: %s path" % (argv[0],)
        exit(1)
    print os.environ['PATH']

    with MyPath(argv[1]) as newpath:
        print newpath
        print os.environ['PATH']

    print os.environ['PATH']
```

`python path.py whatever`

produces:

`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
whatever
whatever
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`

Comment: So can I do that without having a new class?

Comment: Of course you can, by manually doing what you suggested: save the current path, alter it, restore it. The `with` statement is a clean pythonic way of achieving the same thing, with a number of benefits. Mine is one solution, maybe not the only one.

Answer (score -2):

The current environment is available as a mapping through the os module of the standard library.  You can set items in this mapping (dictionary) at the beginning of your program.

From the os module docs:

os.environ

A mapping object representing the string environment. For example, environ['HOME'] is the pathname of your home directory (on some platforms), and is equivalent to getenv("HOME") in C.

Comment: This answer does not address the key "local scope" part of the question.

Comment: I know about os.environ. The question is how I can change it in local scope.